# forcing firefox skip "text nodes" in DOM parsing by javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, firefox, dom, textnode

Hi
I'm writing a javascript code to traverse HTML dom and highlight elements.
My problem is firefox returns whitespaces as text node.
Is there any solution to force it to just return tags? for example I need "firstChild" always return first tag and not any text!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a *node* is an *element* with `node.nodeType === 1`.

You can also implement the new DOM Travelsal API as functions.

```
var dummy = document.createElement("div");
var firstElementChild = ('firstElementChild' in dummy)
    ? function (el) {
      return el.firstElementChild;
    }
    : function (el) {
        el = el.firstChild;
        while (el && el.nodeType !== 1)
            el = el.nextSibling;
        return el;
    }
```

[*usage*](http://jsbin.com/ayili4/7/edit)

```
firstElementChild(el)
```

Comment: What's wrong with *ternary statement*? :) The thing is, neither of them is wrong. I find it more readable in this case that the two alternatives are nested below the actual variable they may get into. Also there are less words and brackets involved. Finally you don't have to read/type firstElementChild 3x.

Comment: To each their own, but I was always under the impression that accepted practice was that ternary statements should never be more than one line for readability (that if they were more, you should break it out to an `if` statement).  To each their own, but some would consider this poor form (pedantic, I know, but worth noting)...

Comment: I never cared for practise. I use *common-sense* instead. If something is readable at first sight, there's nothing worry about. You figured out what the intention of the code was, didn't you? Maybe even faster then an `if-else` branch. Only your *prejudice* made you to say: "It's not ok". :)

Comment: @galambalazs I use _common-sense_ and it feels _wrong_ . Don't abuse syntax like that. It doesn't feel right in javascript.

Comment: @Raynos - How's that an abuse? It's **valid syntax**, used for what it's intended to do (conditionals). Your only reasoning is "I don't like it, so it's bad." Very academic. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`element.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.firstElementChild) instead. Unfortunately, this [isn't supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#traversal) in IE8 and below.

Alternatively, you might want to write a small function to crawl the `childNode`s until you find the next `element` node.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try one of the other DOM traversal methods, such as a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTreeWalker).